Cant download OpenPose prerequisites, bad URL
I'm trying to compile the openpose to use it with the python API. I tried following the CMake Configuration step here but it fails, I tried to read a bit into it and it seems like my third party folder zips are empty.
I tried to download them manually from here but the URLs are dead. Someone knows what I can do to download it?
URL Example

Disclaimer: not the author of the zip, be cautious.
Seems to be available here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnrMnbcjJgECo4UTVRJ5Un1xvcuQDA?e=DU3d1g
From https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/2227#issuecomment-1851689454
